# Start multiple jobs from inside a scheduled job

Tags: powershell, scheduled-tasks, jobs

Is it possible to have a scheduled-job start multiple jobs?
I tried it and simply nothing happened.

```
Register-scheduledjob -scriptblock {$args[0] | foreach {start-job -scriptblock {
$xyz = gc -path PATH
$xyz >> test.txt}}} -argumentlist $var
```

Thanks for help in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got the problem. If the scheduled job finishes its task before the jobs that got started by it - the scheduled job will simply also shut down the others.

If I put a

```
sleep -s 30
```

in it works absolutely fine.